# How can only developer see an specific frontend on production store Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-theme

is there a way to only me see an specific frontend I'm developing?

The store is on production and I have no additional space to create a mirror from this site.

Answer (score 0):

By following below steps you can achieve it:

1> Register as a customer and assign unique customer group to it.

2> Write one `observer class` for listen event `predispatch` for every controller.

3> here you can put your specific urls and allow for only your customer group.

Answer (score 0):

Just do condition on your html  using below:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == "Your ip address"){ ?>
<!-- your html goes here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Call theme according IP:

add below code on your xml which is in all page

```
<default>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="modulename/theme" name="custom.theme"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Create Block file in your custom extension:

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_Theme extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == 'Your ip address') {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->setTheme('default');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This solution looks great. Is there a way to redirect that IP to load the theme folder I'm working on?